# Change carousel controls on boostrap. Too wide. And horrible frame

Tags: html, css, carousel

Could please help me? I make a carousel with cards, but the controls are too large and have and "not so nice border" could help me to sort it out?. This is my code. Danke!

```css
<button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
   </button>
   <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-slide="next">
     <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
   </button>
```

[example of how the slide carousel control is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jir0n.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the button styling, just changed the elements from  to  resolved for me.

```
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" style="align-self: flex-start;" type="button" data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide="next">
     <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
```